# get function load in two pages/views codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

```
  public function get_resto(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $this->load->model('RestoModel');
    $where = array('id' => $id);
    $row = $this->RestoModel->getRow( $where );
    $data['pictures'] = $this->RestoModel->getPictures($id);
    $data['menus'] = $this->RestoModel->getMenus($id);
    $data['r'] = $row;
    $this->load->view('restaurants/resto', $data);      
}
```

I want to call this function also to another page.
$this->load->view('member/resto', $data);

How would i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save your instance to an other variable...

Like:

```
$myObject = new MyClass();
```

Then you can call public functions outside the Class like this:

```
$myObject->myFunc();
```

Insteed of "this" you have to use the variable where you store the ObjectInstance